# Convert string that represent local time into UTC Date

Tags: swift3

I am trying to convert a string "2017-04-11 13:00" that represent local time into Date as UTC. How to do that in swift3 ?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, take a look at DateFormatter class and try using the dateFormat `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = "2017-04-11 13:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let requiredDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
```